# WiX Compile Error Creating Custom Dialog

Tags: user-interface, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I've been trying to insert a custom dialog into the `WixUI_InstallDir` UI sequence. I have a "main" file named `Product.wxs` and the custom dialog in another file named `InstallTypeDlg.wxs` - both of which are present in `Installer.wixproj`.

Within `InstallTypeDlg.wxs`, I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
      <UI>
        <Dialog Id="InstallTypeDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Select Install Type">

          <Control Id="InstallTypeSelection" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="20" Y="55" Width="330" Height="120" Property="InstallType">
            <RadioButtonGroup Property="InstallType">
              <RadioButton Text="Type 01" Value="1" X="5" Y="0" Width="250" Height="15" />
              <RadioButton Text="Type 02" Value="2" X="5" Y="20" Width="250" Height="15" />
            </RadioButtonGroup>
          </Control>

          <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
          <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" />
          <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
            <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
          </Control>

          <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgBannerBitmap)" />
          <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
          <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
          <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgTitle)" />
          <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgDescription)" />
          <Control Id="TypicalText" Type="Text" X="60" Y="85" Width="280" Height="20" Text="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgTypicalText)" />
        </Dialog>
      </UI>
    </Fragment>
  </Wix>
```

I reference this custom dialog in `Product.wxs` thus:

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" />

<UI Id="MyWixUI_InstallDir">
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

  <DialogRef Id="InstallTypeDlg" />

  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallTypeDlg" Order="4">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallTypeDlg">1</Publish>
</UI>
```

Now, when I compile this project, I get the following error:

`InstallTypeDlg.wxs(8,0): error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:InstallType' in section 'Fragment:'.`

I have no idea why. Have I forgotten something? :-/

I'm fairly new to WiX, having only picked it up yesterday. Any help would be much appreciated.

I am using [Wix 3.5.2415.0](http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/3.5.2415.0/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably, you just need to define that property before using it, i.e.:

```
<Property Id="InstallType" Value="some default value" />
```

Comment: Works, thanks! The tutorials I've read don't mention that, and I assumed the property was auto-created from the <Control> tag

Comment: Great it works. Usually, if you get the error like this, this means you have to define the entity being referenced.

Comment: Thanks. I had already defined the property, but didn't assign it a default value. That made all the difference.

Comment: Thanks. Same as bigfoot. Need to set the value of the property up front.